# How to implement undo and redo in a crud type of application when using reagent and re-frame?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

Although on the re-frame home page it says that "Save and Undo become quite easy.", the re-frame example app 'todomvc' has no code which implements an undo / redo feature.

When using an OO language like Java it is common practice to implement undo / redo by using a command interface for actions performed, store these with their 'inverses' and (re-)execute those from the collection of stored command objects.

Although I have read the page of Clojure equivalents of common OO Design Patterns [including, Command here.](http://mishadoff.com/blog/clojure-design-patterns/#command) it would be helpful to see undo / redo implemented with reagent, re-frame in some example or application.

Q. **How to implement undo and redo in a crud type of application when using reagent and re-frame?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-frame actually has a built-in `undoable` middleware for handlers. Unfortunately the (otherwise excellent) doc doesn't cover it at all; I only understood how it works by looking at the source code.

Using it is quite easy:

```
(register-handler :your-handler
  ; this middleware from re-frame.core is all you need to enable undo
  (undoable "String that explains your action, optional")
  (fn [db [_]] ...))
```

After doing that, if you want to undo the action, simply `(dispatch [:undo])`. To re-apply the action it's `(dispatch [:redo])`.

The middleware works under the hood by simply saving mutated versions your app-db between each call. The default max undo depth is 50.

For more info, read [this file](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/src/re_frame/middleware.cljs#L129) and [this one](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/src/re_frame/undo.cljs).

Comment: A tiny correction to the above (almost at the level of nitpicking). It is `(dispatch [:undo])`  and `(dispatch [:redo])`

Comment: @MikeThompson : I don't think it's nitpicking at all; thanks for the syntax error correction! I fixed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

One of the approaches is just to store the state history - this will be memory-efficient as Clojure(Script) will in effect store it as a history of changes under the hood.

Please see [this link](https://reagent-project.github.io/news/cloact-reagent-undo-demo.html) for a very short and clear example!